# Spring batch to read a key= value and load it into DB

Tags: spring-batch

I am new to spring batch and having a feed file with key param values in .txt format. I need to load the file into Mysql DB using spring batch. Is there any way to read a text file with key value message. Two rows are separated by an empty line and the delimiter is '='.

Sample File:

```
Name=Jack
Id=ADC12345
ClassId=7018
Rank=-326

Name=Gile
Id=FED12345
ClassId=7018
Rank=-32
```

Name, ID, ClassId and Rank are the column values.

Comment: [link]http://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/[link]

Comment: Look at the example that does the opposite process, the difference is that you must invest the reader and the writer and also if you want to read a file must have the same format, in that you publish, you have lines and spaces with different format [link]http://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/[link]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working solution (you just need a blank line after the last record or it won't be read) :

1) Declare your business object :

```java
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private String id;
    private Integer classId;
    private Integer rank;

    // Getter + Setters

}
```

2) Declare a custom itemstreamreader to which you will delegate the actual FlatFileItemReader :

```java
public class CustomMultiLineItemReader implements ItemStreamReader<Student> {

    private FlatFileItemReader<FieldSet> delegate;

    @Override
    public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
        delegate.open(executionContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
        delegate.update(executionContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
       delegate.close();
    }

    // Getter + Setters
}
```

3) Override its read method to manually map your multiline records :

```java
public Student read() throws Exception {
    Student s = null;

    for (FieldSet line = null; (line = this.delegate.read()) != null;) {

        if (line.getFieldCount() == 0) {
            return s; // Record must end with footer
        } else {

            String prefix = line.readString(0);
            if (prefix.equals("Name")) {
                s = new Student(); // Record must start with header
                s.setName(line.readString(1));
            }
            else if (prefix.equals("Id")) {
               s.setId(line.readString(1));
            }
            else if (prefix.equals("ClassId")) {
                s.setClassId(line.readInt(1));
            }
            else if (prefix.equals("Rank")) {
                s.setRank(line.readInt(1));
            }
        }
    }
   return null;
}
```

4) Declare the reader in the step and configure it :

```xml
<bean class="xx.xx.xx.CustomMultiLineItemReader">
    <property name="delegate">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
            <property name="resource" value="file:${YOUR_FILE}"></property>
            <property name="linesToSkip" value="0"></property>
            <property name="lineMapper">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper">
                    <property name="tokenizers">
                        <map>
                            <entry key="*">
                                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                                    <property name="delimiter" value="="></property>
                                </bean>
                            </entry>                                                   
                        </map>
                    </property>
                    <property name="fieldSetMappers">
                        <map>
                            <entry key="*">
                                 <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.PassThroughFieldSetMapper" />
                            </entry>
                        </map>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I used a `PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper` to associate line content (here : *) with the corresponding lineTokenizer and lineMapper (even though it's useless in this case).

Then, the `PassThroughFieldSetMapper` lets the reader do the mapping, and the `DelimitedLineTokenizer` splits the line on the "=" character.

Comment: Now i am able to parse the feed but facing issue while writing into my SQL db. Using class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter" to write the data.Not getting any error.

Comment: @Amuthan What is the issue? Do the data get inserted in the database? What do the logs say?

Comment: Not able to insert data into DB. Below line is the odd one from normal successful job load logs. Not getting any errors. Even job was successful but data not getting loaded into DB.                                                                                                              INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
Apr 28, 2016 4:33:01 AM org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory <init>
INFO: SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, Hana]

Comment: @Amuthan Can you create a new question with your writer configuration, a bit more content from the logs and the problem?

Comment: Created new question 36911322.

Comment: @Amuthan Thanks, please mark this one as resolved since the reading part seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 challenges with this input format

1. start/end for a complete item
2. splitting the item in key/value pairs

one solution could be to use a custom RecordSeparatorPolicy and custom LineMapper, like

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.FieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.separator.RecordSeparatorPolicy;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FieldSet;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;

public class ReaderKeyValueTest {
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        FlatFileItemReader<Map<String, String>> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Map<String, String>>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("keyvalue.txt"));
        // custom RecordSeparatorPolicy
        reader.setRecordSeparatorPolicy(new RecordSeparatorPolicy() {

            @Override
            public String preProcess(final String record) {
                // empty line is added to the previous 'item'
                if (record.isEmpty()) {
                    return record;
                } else {
                    // line with content means it is part of an 'item', lets enhance it with adding a separator
                    return record + ",";
                }
            }

            @Override
            public String postProcess(final String record) {
                return record;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isEndOfRecord(final String record) {
                // the end of a record is marked with the last key/value pair for "Rank"
                if (record.contains("Rank=")) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        DefaultLineMapper<Map<String, String>> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<Map<String, String>>();
        // the key/value pairs are separated with ',', so we can use the standard DelimitedLineTokenizer here
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer());
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new FieldSetMapper<Map<String, String>>() {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> mapFieldSet(final FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
                Map<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                // split each "Key=Value" and add to the Map
                for (int i = 0; i < fieldSet.getValues().length; i++) {
                    String[] entry = fieldSet.getValues()[i].split("=");
                    item.put(entry[0], entry[1]);
                }
                return item;
            }
        });
        reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
        reader.open(new ExecutionContext());
        Map<String, String> item;
        while ((item = reader.read()) != null) {
            System.out.println(item.toString());
        }
        reader.read();
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

the sysout produces

```
{ClassId=7018, Id=ADC12345, Name=Jack, Rank=-326}
{ClassId=7018, Id=FED12345, Name=Gile, Rank=-32}
```